# What's the best way to capture a digital signature in Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, electronic-signature, signaturepad

Do I use a jquery plugin and then store it as an image? Is it ok to use that signature to populate a pdf for the form they are signing? Totally lost on this one so any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Thomas Bradley's library before to accept, store, and recall signatures in a Rails 4 app. Most of my users were signing on iPads out in the field, but you can draw with a mouse or whatever input you want.

I'd recommend reading his documentation to see if this would work for your needs, as well:

[SignaturePad on GitHub](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad)